# What is perek 4 in Rambam's Hilchos De'os doing there?

Tags: halacha, rambam

I'm certainly no expert, but most of perek 4 in Hilchos De'os seems like it doesn't fit with the rest of Hilchos De'os. It's all about maintaining a healthy body. Any ha'aros on why it's there? Am I misunderstanding it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See ibid. 3:2-3, which explains how "all of one's actions should be exclusively in order to know Hashem," and that this includes maintaining a healthy body in order to serve Hashem. Chapter 4 is a direct continuation of that.

Comment: This is the same view expressed in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, siman 32. Thus, it should be understood that this view of Rambam (a Rishon) was accepted amongst later Acharonim.